# ValueGetter is not working with grouped rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

When I use `valueGetter` for `columnDefs`, instead of showing the values only if the rows are collapsed, it will fill all the cells even if the group is not expanded yet.
Here is an example of the problem 
[image]

And here is the desired behaviour, I can obtain such a thing with `field` option: 
[image]

And here is the code I'm using to define the for each calendar day

```
{
          headerName: moment(day).format("DD"),
          colId: moment(day).unix(),
          valueGetter: () => "12",
          width: 58
}
```

Comment: dang. having this exact same problem.

Comment: @jpro I remember that I got away by creating ugly custom renderers